# Installing calendar plugin in TiddlyWiki

Tags: plugins, tiddlywiki

I am trying to install [this calendar plugin](http://www.tiddlytools.com/#CalendarPlugin) in Tiddly Wiki.

Although I have been following different tutorials, I haven't succeded so far.
What I do is:

- I copy/paste the source code into a new tiddler
- I save it and I tag it as systemConfig
- I save the changes in the wiki. It creates a new file (it goes to my downloads folder)
- I reload again this new file and then, I try to write `<<calendar>>` to see if there is a calendar in the a new tiddler

But nothing happens. 
Actually I haven't been able to install so far any of the plugins, though it should be easy. Any help?

Comment: Are you talking about TW5? Do you need a date picker or a calendar plugin?

Answer (score 2):

I believe tiddlytools only works with TiddlyWiki 2. So, if you are using the default version of tiddlywiki on tiddlywiki.com (which is version 5), none of the plugins on tiddlytools will work.

Comment: anyone can help about this issue? I need a calendar date picker in version 5 too